# cubic function of the two points (2,0) (4,0)

Tags: interpolation

How can I find the cubic function of two points. I have the $y$-intersect $(0,2)$ and the $y=0$ intersect with the x-axis $(4,0)$. The equation should have the form $y=x^3+2$. But when I try to calculate the intersect with the $x$ axis by using the cubic root of $2$ I get $1.2599$. But using a plotting program the true value should be much smaller.

*It's been a while since school math. What is my thinking mistake?*

Edit: Corrected $y$-intersect point

Thanks to the answer the curve is:

[y=$(-x^3)(\frac{1}{32})+2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%28-x%C2%B3%29%2a%281%2F32%29%2B2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to completely define a cubic function, you need four distinct points. So it is not very surprising to me that you are getting these conflicting results, since two points leaves a great deal of ambiguity.

That said, if you know in advance your equation looks like $y=ax^3+b$, then two points is enough to specify it. [Note: when I say "looks like" this I mean it has no $x$ or $x^2$ terms].

The general method for finding the coefficients in problems like this is to plug in the points for $x$ and $y$. This leaves a *linear* system of equations in the coefficients, which is then solvable by standard methods (like substitution or elimination).

In your case, we have the $y$-intercept $(0,2)$ and the root $(4,0)$, which gives
$$0=a(4)^3+b$$
$$2=a(0)^3+b$$

The second equation immediately gives $b=2$, and then by substituting into the first we see that $0=64a+2$ and so $a=-\frac{1}{32}$.

I'm not sure where you went wrong precisely because you didn't show your reasoning all the way through [you did write the $y$-intercept as $(2,0)$ instead of $(0,2)$, though I don't think that was the real problem]. But hopefully with this solution you can diagnose the problem yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Either your equation is wrong or your $x$-axis intercept is wrong.  If the equation is right, the  intercept should be $( - \sqrt[3]{2},0)$.